# xcode 12: The file “app name” couldn't be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: ios, xcode12

Running my app with Xcode 12
and show this :

[image]

and now the old Xcode 11.3 is the same result.(before it is ok)

why for this? thanks all.

Tying:

---- 1

replace info.plist from create new project with the same name.

/ the problem still exists. /

---- 2
delete values:

[image]

[image]

/ the problem still exists /

Comment: try "Targets->Build Settiing ->VALID_ARCHS , delete(set default)",  and "Excluded Architectures " do the same

Comment: now it is empty, same result showing (Set it is empty on the Xcode 11.3 then open with Xcode 12, them all are empty)

Comment: default value is "VALID_ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64",  Excluded Architectures is empty

Comment: delete mean "Click delete on the keyboard", not set empty

Comment: @burningsun thanks, it it fixed my issues.  please make an answer, then i check mark.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1."Targets->Build Setting ->VALID_ARCHS ", Click delete on the keyboard
2."Targets->Build Setting ->Excluded Architectures", Click delete on the keyboard

Comment: if link some custom frameworks need do the same actions.

Comment: Thank you! Was stuck on this for days! Had VALID_ARCHS: empty but didn't realize I had to delete the entry completely.

Comment: In XCode 12.4, I cannot delete either of the entry, only set its value to empty. Getting the error for device build and not the simulator.

Answer (score 4):

How I fixed this issue in my case are 2 options:

1. Updated BUILD SETTINGS > VALID_ARCHS with $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
2. Completely delete SETTINGS > VALID_ARCHS entry

Comment: thanks, @burningsun is answer is right.  and your the 2 option is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with one of above, following solved my case.

"Targets->Build Setting ->VALID_ARCHS ", delete it.